# How to fix my dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

I am trying to create a pure CSS Dropdown menu. I need your help to solve one problem which doesn't let me proceed. This is the source code: [Here is the problem](http://pastebin.com/jKwisNM9)

I don't know how to explain my problem, so just take mouse over "Podpunkt 4", and you will see for sure what I want to get rid of.

Comment: put the sub-elements of product 4 in a separate div

Comment: hm, I don't know what you wanted to show by giving me this link

Comment: @mic4ael it's better to provide a demo of the problem than a pastebin link